# Filtering a list of names with ReactJS using data from RelayJS without calling GrpahQL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

I'm stuck in wondering if I can filter a list of names which I receive from Relay and graphql-java server without the need of making calls, without making any changes in my GrpahQL schema and only using ReactJS for this purpose.
---MobX as a state management library can be a decision but I should first store all the Relay result.

Comment: "filter a list of names" -- why do you even need ReactJS specific things to do that? Can't plain JavaScript do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Caveat emptor*: I'm newish at `Relay` as well & struggling with these same concepts. But, given the relative dearth of accessible information on `Relay`, I thought it'd be helpful to try and layout the key concepts here. My understanding could be wrong, so I'd love it if anyone who found a mistake in my code/reasoning would comment/edit.

Filtering took awhile for me to 'click' as well. It depends on where you keep the data you'll use to filter, but let's assume the `name` field lives on your `Users Type`, and the query is something like this:

```
viewer {
  allUsers {
    edges {
      node {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And let's say your top-level `NameList` component looked like this:

```
class NameList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.users.edges
          .map(u => {
            <NameItem name={u.node} />
           })
         }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Relay.createContainer(NameList, {
  initialVariables: { first: 10 },
  fragments: {
    users: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Viewer {
      allUsers(first: $first) {
         edges {
           node {
             ${NameItem.getFragment('user')}
           }
          }
        }
      }
    ` 
  }
})
```

And your `NameItem` setup was simply:

```
class NameItem extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            Name: {this.props.user.name}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

Relay.createContainer(NameItem, {
  initialVariables: {},
  fragments: {
    user: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on User {
      name
      }
    ` 
  }
})
```

Consider the generalizable pattern here:

**The List Component**

A `List` component takes a fragment on the top-level `Type` in the query--in this case, `Viewer`, from a `Relay container`.

`List` also inserts a `fragment` on behalf of its `Item` child at the level of the `User Type`.

In other words, it captures an array of `User` objects it's supposed to pass down to the `Item` component.

If this wasn't `Relay`, and instead was, say, `Redux`, this component might simply pass `state.users` to the `Item` component. You can do that because, at some point, you've manually extracted all your `User`s from your own back-end and loaded them into `Redux`. But since `Relay` does the hard thinking for you, it needs a teensy bit more information than `Redux`.

**The Item Component**

This is even more simple. It expects an entity of type `User` and renders the `name`. Besides syntax, the functionality here isn't much different from a similar component in a `Redux` setup.

**So really**, without the complexity of `Relay` on top, all you have is an array of items that you're rendering. In vanilla `React`, you'd simply filter the array prior to (or during) your call to `.map()` in `render()`.

However, with `Relay`, the `fragment` handed to the `child` is opaque to the `parent`--i.e., the `List` is handing a blind package to the `Item`, so it can't make a decision on whether or not to pass it down based on the `fragment`'s content.

The solution in this contrived example is pretty simple: just peel-off the `name` field at the `parent` and `child` level.  Remember: `Relay` is about components telling `GraphQL` what data they need. Your `List` component needs whatever fields it intends on filtering on--no more, no less.

If we modify the above `List` container:

```
...
users: () => Relay.QL`
    fragment on Viewer {
      allUsers(first: $first) {
         edges {
           node {
             name
             ${NameItem.getFragment('user')}
           }
          }
        }
      }
    `
```

And then we update our `render` function:

```
 <div>
        {this.props.users.edges
          .map(u => {
             if (u.node.name == "Harvey") {
               <NameItem name={u.node} />
             }
           })
         }
 </div>
```

Then we've achieved basic filtering without needing `mobx`, more server trips, etc.